# Not working jQuery change function when right click checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, right-click

I have following issue,
There is [image: table] and if I right click table row,checkbox checked.

This is the right click checkbox checked code.

```
$('tr.check').contextmenu(function (e) {
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].check_row').prop('checked', true);
        return false;
  });
```

But the issue is I want to get `row id` number after change checkbox.
What is the correct way to do this??

Comment: Do you have any change event bound to checkbox? Is your question how to trigger it?

Comment: @A.Wolff : yes,that is I want.

Comment: So it would do it: `$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].check_row').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');`

Comment: Thanks your support.But it's not working yet.

Comment: Can you post some HTML that you use for this table so that I can try and help you?

Comment: And can you post change handler code? BTW, are you sure you have a change event bound to this chackbox that returns row id? Your question is missing some important info for sure. You have to post minimalistic sample replicating issue. Posting picture doesn't really help. And if you just want row id from contextmenu event, use `console.log($(this).closest('tr').prop('id'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct one that I really want.

```
function populate_context_menu($object){
                var ischecked = $($object).is(':checked');
                var jsonString = JSON.stringify(values);

                var ischecked = $($object).is(':checked');
                if (ischecked)
                {
                    $("#checked-a").fadeIn(200);

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "files/dropdown_menu",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {files_ids: jsonString},
                        success: function (res) {
                            if (res)
                            {
                                $("div#result").show();
                                $("div#value").html(res.jsonString);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    if (values.length === 0) {
                        $("#checked-a").fadeOut(200);
                    }
                }
            };


 $(".selected_check").change(function () {

                    populate_context_menu(this);

            });
```

This is for right click

```
$('tr.check').contextmenu(function (e) {
                $cb = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].selected_check');
                $($cb).attr('checked', 'checked');                                       
                populate_context_menu($cb);

                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you check or uncheck using `prop()` or `attr()` method you have to trigger event using `change()` or `trigger('change')`.

```
$('tr.check').contextmenu(function (e) {
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].check_row').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].check_row').change(); // trigger change event
        //OR
        //$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].check_row').trigger('change'); 

         return false;
  })
```

;